# What do animal cells store pigment in?

Tags: cell-biology, pigmentation

So I know plants store pigment in chloroplasts, chromoplasts, etc., but what do animal cells store pigment in? For example, is there like a chromoplast for melanin in the human body?

I tried Googling my question and didn't find anything, but maybe I was looking at the wrong sources.

Comment: I read through the article you linked and it didn't seem to have an organelle or something that contained melanin. I've never heard of melanine, but maybe it's a variation of melanin.

Comment: You want to read the Wikipedia page on [Melanosomes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melanosome).

Comment: Cool, I did. That was really helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Melanine is produced and stored in [**melanocytes**](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3834696/). They contain **[melanosomes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melanosome)** that are organelles that store melanine.